# About MongoDB Max size(16MB)

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

For a document in a collection, MongoDB max size is 16MB. How to deal with BSON which size over 16MB?
When use GridFS to deal with pictures, mp3, it looks easy .
But how to use it to deal BSON?

Comment: watch this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: Also worth reading through the following. Often large documents are a sign that an alternate data model could be a better choice. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's specification for GridFS actually splits the file up into chunks https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/, currently 255KB